# Displaying NSMutableArray from Parse Outside the Block

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have asked this question a couple times and have not had any success in solving the question. So i have refined my code. I am trying to create an NSMutableArray and store data from Parse in it. Then I am trying to display the NSMutableArray on the screen. I am able to display the text when the NSLog is inside the block but not when it is outside the block. Please help as I have been struggling with why I can not access the NSMutableArray outside the block. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
//.h file
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface IncomeTransactionViewController : UIViewController  <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *accountArray;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *accountArray;

@end


//.m file
#import "IncomeTransactionViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface IncomeTransactionViewController ()

@end

@implementation IncomeTransactionViewController

@synthesize accountArray;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    accountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Account"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query orderByDescending:@"startingBalance"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            [accountArray addObject:object[@"name"]];
        }

        for (NSString *obj in accountArray) {
            NSLog(@"Inside Block %@",obj);
        }
    }];


    for (NSString *obj in accountArray) {
        NSLog(@"Outside Block%@",obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the "outside block" code is called first and then the findObjectsInBackground is occurring. As a result, your NSMutableArray is not being populated at the time "outside block" code is called. I'm not sure why you would want to put it outside the block anyway? Just put the rest of your code that you want on the main thread inside the block.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
//this happens first
    accountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Account"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query orderByDescending:@"startingBalance"];

   //this happens third
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            [accountArray addObject:object[@"name"]];
        }

        for (NSString *obj in accountArray) {
            NSLog(@"Inside Block %@",obj);
        }
    }];

//this happens second...note that accountArray is empty at this point
    for (NSString *obj in accountArray) {
        NSLog(@"Outside Block%@",obj);
    }
}
```